# handling multiple component presentations in Dreamweaver Template Building block in SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am working on Dreamweaver TBB in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. In the TBB I am using the data from different component presentations.

```
My Template Building Block looks like this.
```

Main Component:

```html
<div>@@Component.Schema.Title@@</div>

<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Fields.link" -->

    @@RenderComponentPresentation(Field, "tcm:1-8142-32")@@

<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Component Template: tcm:1-8142-32

Its DWT TBB looks like this.

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Fields.text" --> 
    <div>@@RenderComponentField("text",0)@@</div>
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

When I previewed the Component I got the output and all component presentations executed as expected.

Output:

```
SchemaName
    data1
    data2
```

Then I created the Page with the page TBB.

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
            @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
        <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The output is not as expected. The Component Template "tcm:1-8142-32" is not executed.

output:

```
SchemaName
```

I want to make SiteEdit to linked component also.

Do I need to add extra templates to the existing ones? I am using Tridion 2012 UI.

I came to know that we need add `isQueryBased`, property must be set to true.

If yes, can any one help the command to set it true?

I don't know where the problem lies.

Can any one help me out to modify the code and implement SiteEdit for the embedded Component?

Comment: Updated the question answers given. But the problem is not solved.

Comment: I wanted to implement the site edit for the components linked to main component through component linking.

Comment: I updated my answer for you, hopefully this will help

Comment: Which version of SiteEdit and Tridion are you using? There is no "Tridion SP1" and also no "SiteEdit 2012", so which are they? I'll  assume you are using Tridion 2011 SP1 with SiteEdit 2009 SP3, but please update the question with the correct version numbers.

Comment: Edited question with correct versions. Sorry for the wrong inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a Dreamweaver template RenderComponenetPresentation() can be called in two ways.

1. If you are iterating through the Component Presentations on a page ( which I think is what you are doing?)
2. If for some reason you need to Render a component with a different template, not the one you've added it to the page with.

Assuming number one is what you are doing, then you have added the Component to the page with the correct Template. Therefore you can call @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@ with no arguments like this:

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
            @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
        <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
    </body>
</html>
```

"IsQueryBased" is unrelated to your problem. This is connected to SiteEdit and Dynamic Component Presentations.

Update -

It looks like you have 2 questions here:

1. How can I call RenderComponentPresentation for linked components
2. How can i make the Component be "SiteEditable"

Looking at question 1 - Assuming you the array of components are not component presentations on the page your initial method was almost correct:

```
@@RenderComponentPresentation(Component.ID,"tcm:xx-xx-xx")@@
```

You should be able to get the component ID from the array, but you will need to specify the ComponentTemplate ID yourself.

For testing purposes, first of all hard code the Tcm ID of the Component Template.

Since putting Tcm ids in templates is bad practice, you will then need to write a TBB to make this available in the package for you. You can then replace the Tcm Id you used for testing.

In relation to your SiteEdit question, [this guide](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/siteedit-2009-essentials.aspx) might help, if not post a new question detailing the exact nature of your issue.

Comment: I have tried with that also. No change in the output. I am trying to implement the site edit for Components linked to main component.